# Script working only on page reload

Tags: jquery, css, debugging

I'm using jQuery to align images on an horizontal view website, but the script only works when I reload the page.

http://joliannelm.steveforest.com/edition/roux-de-service.html

The script is called just before

This is the script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var width = 0;

    $('#page img').each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    $('#page').css('width', width + 50);

});
```

Once the page is reloaded it's OK, but if you clear the cache, it's back...

Someone knows why?? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably a timing problem: The `ready` event is fired when the DOM is ready - this can be before the images are loaded. Because you're not giving the images fixed `width` attributes, you need them to be loaded before you can tell their width.

This is where the [`load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is the most appropriate trigger.

```
$(window).load(function() {  ... your code here
```

unlike `ready`, `load` will wait for all associated files - images, style sheets, JavaScript files etc.