# Why the script works only I reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use jquery to load elem in a table. This is the code:

In the file.html the code of the table is:

```
<table id="tabella_ban_email" class="table table-condensed table-responsive table-hover"></table>
```

and in the script.js the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var email_table=$('#tabella_ban_email');
  if(email_table!=null && email_table!=undefined){
    $.ajax({
      url:'....',
      success: function(data) {
        data.split(',').forEach(function(email){
          email_table.append('<tr><th>'+email+'</th><th><input type="button" name="'+email+'" value="X">');
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The program works only I refresh the page if I not reload the page the program doesn't work.

Comment: Check the console for more information?

Comment: maybe that is because it is only in the `document.ready()` function have you thought about that? really think about when `document.ready()` gets called?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Script working only on page reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969144/script-working-only-on-page-reload?rq=1). Did you even search before asking?

Comment: Side note. If statement condition `(email_table!=null && email_table!=undefined)` makes no sense. jQuery constructor always returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});


$(window).load(function() {
 // Executes when page is fully loaded
 alert("window is loaded");
});

Use $(window).load ... it might work in your scenario
```

Comment: I have two questions i.e  1) Is (document).ready is getting called??? 2) If it getting called what 'email_table' consists??

Comment: I think it is a problem of loading.The component of page doesn't load when the script is execute. With your suggest I replace $(document).ready(function() with $(window).load(function()  in my code

Comment: What actually mean this 'The component of page doesn't load when the script is execute' . window.load will not execute until the whole content is loaded in the screen. confirm whether it is executing or not? if not check is there any exception show in the console.