# Javascript runs on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using this javascript to edit a url to sort a list generated by a none editable plugin in wordpress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sortRegex = /\[sort_by\]=\w*/;
function priceHighZ() {
  location.href = location.href.replace('[sort_order]=ASC', '[sort_order]=DESC').replace(sortRegex, '[sort_by]=price');
}
function priceLowZ() {
  location.href = location.href.replace('[sort_order]=DESC', '[sort_order]=ASC').replace(sortRegex, '[sort_by]=price');
}
function dateHighZ() {
  location.href = location.href.replace('[sort_order]=ASC', '[sort_order]=DESC').replace(sortRegex, '[sort_by]=date');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('priceHighZ').addEventListener('click', priceHighZ);
  document.getElementById('priceLowZ').addEventListener('click', priceLowZ);
  document.getElementById('dateHighZ').addEventListener('click', dateHighZ);
});
</script>
```

It only works once the page has loaded for the first time, and you reload the page. It doesn't work on first load.

Is there a problem with DOMContentLoaded, that could cause this to work only once the page is reloaded?

I've [looked at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969144/script-working-only-on-page-reload) but not sure how to apply this example to my code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery .ready() event to be sure that DOM is loaded before execution of the script (like in your link example). But with wordpress you use `jQuery` instead of the alias `$`. Using the alias `$` with wordpress is possible with for example adding `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {

    var sortRegex = /\[sort_by\]=\w*/;
    function priceHighZ() {
        location.href = location.href.replace('[sort_order]=ASC', '[sort_order]=DESC').replace(sortRegex, '[sort_by]=price');
    }
    function priceLowZ() {
        location.href = location.href.replace('[sort_order]=DESC', '[sort_order]=ASC').replace(sortRegex, '[sort_by]=price');
    }
    function dateHighZ() {
        location.href = location.href.replace('[sort_order]=ASC', '[sort_order]=DESC').replace(sortRegex, '[sort_by]=date');
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('priceHighZ').addEventListener('click', priceHighZ);
        document.getElementById('priceLowZ').addEventListener('click', priceLowZ);
        document.getElementById('dateHighZ').addEventListener('click', dateHighZ);
    });

});

</script>
```

You could use jQuery syntax instead of pure javascript replacing for example in: 
`document.getElementById('dateHighZ')…` replacing it by `$('#dateHighZ')…`.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above example, but the javascript is still working in the same way, ie will only work on reload of the page :/ Any thoughts on what else it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the Id's you are binding with click event are not loaded in the DOM in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Javascript @cris_dpa where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that your javascript is running before page is loaded. But when you refresh page is loaded from local and page/element is ready before script. According to MDN:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event - load
>   - should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page

Give it a chance like this

```
document.addEventListener('load', function () {
  ...
}
```

Comment: See the code example above. I have this in the code `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {`

Comment: did you try `load` instead of `DOMContentLoaded` as i mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. Yup, same problem with load in there instead of DOMContentLoaded.